# Chinatown in Seoul

Tags: restaurants, seoul

Is there any kind of [Chinatown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinatown) in [Seoul](https://wikivoyage.org/wiki/Seoul), or at least a place with many authentic [Chinese restaurants](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/China#Eat)?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinatowns_in_Asia#Korea.2C_South) the only official Chinatown is in [Incheon](https://wikivoyage.org/wiki/Incheon), which is further than I'd like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seoul has two 'real' Chinatowns:

1) **Garibong-dong** (가리봉동), down the hill from near Guro (구로) stn exit 3.  This is the larger of the two, and insular to the point that not many Koreans, much less other tourists, venture here.  It's also under threat from a giant redevelopment project that's been imminent for several years, but I was unable to find any confirmation that it's actually started.

2) The vicinity of **Daerim** (대림) stn on subway lines 2 & 7.  [This blog](http://seoulsuburban.com/2010/01/04/daerim-station-%EB%8C%80%EB%A6%BC%EC%97%AD-line-2-%E2%80%93-station-233-line-7-%E2%80%93-station-744/) recommends the streets to the south of exits 11 & 12, and [this blog](http://www.seoulnavi.com/special/5002015) (Japanese only) has better pictures.

Note that these are both pretty low-key collections of shops that cater to Chinese immigrants, and if you can't read the signs, they [doesn't really](https://goo.gl/maps/9lVo3) look [much different](https://goo.gl/maps/HFUaN) from any semi-suburban neighborhood in Seoul — but if the restaurant has its signboard in Chinese characters, it'll be authentic alright.  Possibly too much so, Daerim in particular has a fair number of restaurants that serve/specialize in dog (狗).

Answer (score 4):

According to this [blog](http://kawikaguillermo.com/2012/07/12/travel-seoul-june-6-2012/), there is a "gigantic authentic *unofficial* Chinatown" in Seoul near "Guro-go":

[image: chinatown]

The [address is](http://www.investkorea.org/ikwork/iko/eng/cont/contents.jsp?code=10205050207):

> Yenbian Street: Garibong-dong, Guro-gu

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would you happen to know the latitude/longitude or even better the OpenStreetMap link? :-) Google Maps knows Garibong-dong but not Yenbian Street.